# install DHCP on Windows Server 2016, but not start the Service

Tags: windows-server-2016, dhcp-server, windows-sbs-2008

I am migrating from an Windows SBS 2008 to a new Server 2016 Machine. Now I want to install the DHCP Server on my targetserver and I know how to do that.
In order to avoid 2 servers interfering with each other (DHCP on the source SBS server is still running) I do not want the DHCP service to start right away (which is I think what happens if you go through the Dashboard and add the DHCP role) though so I was wondering if using the PowerShell and tell it to:

> `Install-WindowsFeature -IncludeManagementTools dhcp`

would do what I want: Install the DHCP server on the 2016er Server but not start the service (which I want to do manually after I have prepared everything)

Comment: A dirty way of doing of doing it would be to tell the servers firewall to deny egress DHCP packets on port 68/UDP while you set it up.

Comment: I believe it will add a firewall exception automatically when it's installed so that won't work.

Comment: so, there isn't a clean way to install but not start a DHCP Server? In that case someone advised I can manage 2 parralled DHCP Servers in 'The Active Domain' How would that be done practically? (very inexperienced with Windows server here, so I'd need step-by-step instructions)

Comment: There is. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely install the DHCP role. It isn't functional until you authorize it, configure a Scope, and activate the Scope.

Comment: that'd be actually as it should be. It just looked to me as if it wasn't working like that. ... So I **can** install DHCP, confirgure a scope (all while the current DHCP server is serving IP's to the users without any disruptions) and **only thereafter**, once I want to, Start the DHCP Service on the new server? Or is 'authrorizing' something else then 'start the service'?

Comment: You don't need to do anything. The DHCP server isn't functional until you authorize it, create a scope, and activate the scope. You don't need to do anything with the service.

Comment: found out the 'authoriyinig is something else then 'start the service'. One location where it can happen is the "Server Manager" where I am actually prompet to 'complete DHCP configuration' (which basically leads to authorizing the DHCP Server.